# Como hacer una validacion en C#?

Tags: c#, validación

Soy nuevo en esto de C# y mi pregunta es: ¿como puedo hacer una validación de números para una calculadora?.

Quisiera aplicar la validación en esta parte de mi codigo:

```
float a, b;
Console.Write("INGRESE PRIMER VALOR: ");
a = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("INGRESE SEGUNDO VALOR: ");
b = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Muchas gracias anticipadas!

Comment: Mi amigo en consola ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En vez de utilizar Parse, deberias usar TryParse que devuelve un bool para saber si es valido o no, lo cual si lo combinas con un ciclo while, te quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
using System.Globalization;//libreria a añadir para usar las funcionalidades que mas abajo se menciona.

float a;
float outVariable;
Console.Write("INGRESE PRIMER VALOR: ");
while(!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),
                      NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                      out outVariable))
{
   Console.Write("INGRESE PRIMER VALOR: ");
}//fin del ciclo while

   Console.ReadKey();
```

Saludos